# Do parent selectors take precedence over child selector in CSS?

Tags: css

I had a question about how CSS selectors work between parent and children, and which one would take precedence over the other.

```
<div class="red">
  <div class="blue">
    <div class="green">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you then have

```
   .red .green{
    border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .blue .green{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    }
```

Which one would take effect? And to override a CSS style does it have to be as specific a selector as the one you're trying to override?

Comment: Don't you mean `.red .green` and `.blue .green`? Otherwise you are applying the the first style to both `.red` and `.green`, the second style to `.blue` and `.green`.

Comment: Sorry, yes that's what I meant!

Comment: You also may find [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311629/why-is-the-selector-of-lesser-specificity-than-anything/3311930#3311930) (and the long string of comments to that answer) enlightening.

Answer (score 5):

You should read up on [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

To answer your immediate question, all your selectors carry the same specificity, so in the case of `.green`, the last rule takes precedence: your border would be blue.

Comment: Even though you changed the parameters of your question after I provided my answer, it still applies.

Comment: To override a CSS style does it to have the same level of selectors? 
Or is it just based on the order of the CSS?

Comment: Read the article I linked to :) You'll find the answer is "it depends."

Answer (score 0):

the parent selectors encompass everything within those tags that aren't assigned a value. So in your case the 2nd , you wanted to add text or images there, it would follow in line with that class. The third  would do the same. Think of it like a math equation and parenthesis:

5 x 4 x (3x3) = 180

you would do the parenthesis first then the other factors.

Answer (score 0):

The position of an element has no effect on selector specificity if you are simply using ascendant/descendant selectors.  Note that

```
.red, .green
.blue, .green
```

Select elements separately because of the comma.  That is, the `<div class=red>` and `<div class=green>` are *both* selected, and this would happen no matter if one were a descendant of the other.  I think that you mean to remove the comma.

In that case, the order of the declaration of the rules will take effect with later rules having higher precedence.  That is `.blue, .green` has higher precedence over `.red, .green` even though the specificity is the same simply because it is declared later.